# How to Unlock iPhone 6+

Tags: iphone

I own a company that had purchased two iPhone 6+ on a plan through Manitoba Telephone System. The company was asked to switch to Tellus Mobility which we did and upgraded to 8. An employee left the company and left his iPhone 6+ without passwords and pass codes. I the owner of this company have a use for this phone but I need to get it unlocked and am told i need to contact apple support in order to do this. Can someone point me in the proper direction please?

Comment: Give Apple Support a call and ask to speak to the Enterprise department.

Comment: On apple.com there is both a support area and a [link](https://www.apple.com/contact/) with a lot of ways to contact Apple.

Answer (score 1):

[This Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306) presents the steps to regain access to an iPhone that is otherwise out of reach because of an unknown passcode. You'll almost certainly lose whatever data is now stored on the phone.

Basically, you'll have to erase the phone using iTunes or Recovery Mode. If you didn't make (or have access to) a backup, all the phone's settings and data will be lost.

If neither works, you can [contact Apple](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=kbase&symptom_id=21009) and obtain assistance. You'll undoubtedly have to demonstrate that you or your firm is the original owner of the device.

Good luck!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.